Equivalent functions of 8log(2(x))
This is an assignment so I'm NOT looking for the answer but please help me understand where I went wrong.



Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

What base does $\log $ signify?

base 10 since that's the default

Base 10 is used for pH and for decibels, but in most places you will find that $\log{x}$ is assumed to be $\log_e{x}$. I'm not sure if this has any bearing on this question however.

@RedFive It has a bearing on the answer.

Sure, but not the process? That is what I meant.

Here is a hint for the first one. Note that $\log_b x = {\log x \over \log b}$.
Suppose ${\log x \over \log b} +c = 8 \log 2x= 8 \log x + 8 \log 2$.
Equating the constants gives $c = 8 \log 2$ and ${1 \over \log b} = 8$, from which you can figure out $b$.

Thanks for this answer. I got a function that works but can you explain how you got 1/logb = 8? Did you do logx/logb = 8log2 and if so how did you simplify that to 1/logb = 8?

If the formula holds for all $x$, then it certainly holds for $x=1$. This gives the value for $c$. Then set $x=10$ to get the formula for $b$.

Thanks, I've answered "a" and "b" now. Do you have any thoughts about "c"? The one where the base doesn't change. Using your method or rules of log both get me the same result; where k=256 and m=8. Problem is it's not graphically equivalent to g(x) because the exponent is even instead of odd.

Expand as $\log k + m \log x$ and repeat the process.

Sorry, could I get another hint? I'm still getting k=256 and m=8. Really appreicate the help.

@UnripeMango I got $k=2^8, m=8$.

Because the question asks where you went wrong, consider the following.
In part a you are trying to turn a single log (where the argument is a product) into a sum.
So, the rule you need is $log_a({x\times y})=log_a{x}+log_a{y}$.
In part b you seem to have assumed that $b=10$. A comment above shows the change of base rule which may be a better approach.
In part c the issue is that the domain of $\log_a{x^n}$ is different for $n$ even or odd. When $n$ is odd, the domain is $(0,\infty)$ whereas when $n$ is even, the domain is $x\neq 0$.
These may not seem significant, but the word equivalent is a strong qualifier, so they need to be considered.
I am not going to post actual answers as the question states that you are not looking for them.

Yea that's what I wrote in my explanation. Please read it before commenting.
